# Convert Latitude and Longitude to SCNVector3 in Swift

Tags: swift, scenekit

I am trying to covert the latitude and longitude to a SCNVector3 format. I found this article: http://www.mathworks.com/help/aeroblks/llatoecefposition.html

But not sure how to move forward. Any ideas.

**UPDATE:**

```
 let resturant = Resturant(latitude: 29.963221, longitude: -95.498958)

 let x =  ((self.sceneView.bounds.width/360.0) * (CGFloat(180.0 + resturant.latitude)));
        let y =  ((self.sceneView.bounds.height/180.0) * (CGFloat(90.0 - resturant.longitude)));

        let cube = SCNBox(width: 0.2, height: 0.2, length: 0.2, chamferRadius: 0)
        let material = SCNMaterial()
        material.diffuse.contents = UIColor.red

        cube.materials = [material]

        let node = SCNNode(geometry: cube)
        node.position = SCNVector3(x,2,-5)

        scene.rootNode.addChildNode(node)

        // Set the scene to the view
        sceneView.scene = scene
```

Comment: In what format are you receiving the latitude/longitude values?

Comment: I am not very familiar with that topic, but here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19478200/convert-latitude-and-longitude-to-ecef-coordinates-system is plain C code, translating that to Swift should be straight-forward.

Comment: CLLocation will contain latitude and longitude.

Comment: @johndoe you could set altitude to `0` if it is not relevant to your application.

Comment: Yes lets just say altitude is always 0. How can I find x and z. I have updated the code.